# Find a symmetric matrix for f(x)

Tags: calculus, matrices

Consider the function $f(x,y,z)=2y^{2}+2xy+2xz+2yz$, Find a symmetric matrix $A$ such that $f(x,y,z)$ can be written in the form $(Ax)x=(Ax)^{T}x$, where $x^T = [x y z]$.

Answer (score 2):

You want $A$ to be a matrix such that the entries on the main diagonal are the coefficients of $x^2, y^2$, and $z^2$ and the other entries to be half of the corresponding coefficient.
I hope that makes sense.

So $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 2 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} = 2y^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2yz$.

Just to clarify, a matrix of this form:
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & d & f\\ 
d & b & e\\ 
f & e & c
\end{pmatrix}$

would result in the function $f(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2dxy+2eyz+2fzx$.